# Java: Read/Write compressed objects over TCP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, compression, objectinputstream

I have to transfer some records over TCP though sockets. I used `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` and it worked fine. One critical think is that the socket is opened once and has to remain open through the whole communication but each side reads and writes more than once (so it more like a persistent connection).

I tried to compress the Objects before writing them in order to increase the overall performance and the results were quite encouraging but, since I used `GZIPOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, the memory overhead is too large and in some case I get OutOfMemory error.

I tried `DeflaterOutputStream` but it didn't seem apropriate for writting objects.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post some sample code you are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java serialization is convenient, but rather ineffective both size-wise and in CPU usage. If you want high performance, suggest you use a completely different communication protocol, for example based on [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or something else light-weight.